# Acces vue-msal plugin's exposed object outside of a vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, azure-ad-msal

I use vue-msal plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-msal-2#auth-options--required- to handle microsoft and azure AD authentication for my app.
When inside a vue I have no trouble using `this.$msal` to use the exposed methods such as `signIn()` but what I would like to do is access this object from outside a vue. For example I would like to create a service like the following:

```
import msal from 'vue-msal';
import store from '@/store';

export default {
  logIn(): void {
    msal.signIn();
  },

  logOut(): void {
    msal.signOut();
  },

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return store.getters.logged;
  },

  acquireToken(): Promise<string> {
    return msal.acquireToken();
  },

  onLoginSuccess(): void {
    console.log('login success');
    this.acquireToken().then(token => store.commit('login', token));
  }
};
```

**However** here `msal` refers to the mixin's data object and so is different from `$msal`. Is there a way to access `$msal` from my service?

Comment: Got the same issue. Any luck with using this.$msal in a service class?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a mixin instead?

```
import Vue from "vue";
import "./vue-msal.js";

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
   signOut() {
      this.$msal.signOut();
   },
   isAuthenticated() {
      return this.$msal.isAuthenticated();
   }
  }
});
```

By this, you can still achieve the same goal.